AutoMapper with .Net 8: System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.String get_Item(System.String)
I have tried every approach and none is working.
I upgraded my WebApp MVC project from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 8 (Output type: Console Application).
This project references other projects that some are .Net Framework 4.8.1 based and others .Net 8 class library project
The AutoMapper config Profile (AutoMapperConfig.cs) class lives in a class library .Net 8 project.
Everything was working fine until I upgraded to:
.Net 8 AutoMapper 12.0.1, or 13.0.1 or any other prior versions
This is a sample class Profile mapping, I experimented with this code in AutoMapperConfig.cs, and if I comment it out, the app still doesn't start but at least it fails due to not having the expected class mappings.
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<Client, ClientView>()
        .ForMember(target => target.Properties, source => source.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IsActive, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StatusCode == 1))
        .ReverseMap().ForMember(target => target.Properties, source => source.Ignore());
        
        ...
    }
}

My Startup.cs class has the following calls in it
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
    {
        config.AddProfile(new AutoMapperConfig());
    });

    //Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperConfig());
    });

    //create and configure mapper
    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

I have tried with these different AutoMapper version combos.
AutoMapper 13.0.1 ONLY
OR
AutoMapper 12.0.1 AND AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 12.0.0/12.0.1
My WebApp used to work fine without issues until I upgraded.
But now the WebApp doesn't even start and throws this error:
Error: Earlier it was displayed in the browser, but now I can see it in the log file only if I run VS 2022 with IIS Express.
Error: System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method System.String get_Item(System.String) (Parameter "property")
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc(MemberMap memberMap, Expression destination, MemberInfo destinationMember)
at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.AddPropertyMaps(List1 actions) at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc(Expression createDestination) at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda() at AutoMapper.TypeMap.CreateMapperLambda(IGlobalConfiguration configuration) at AutoMapper.TypeMap.Seal(IGlobalConfiguration configuration) at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.<.ctor>g__Seal|20_0() at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression) at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(Action1 configure)
at eSignWebMVC.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\denkhnin\Documents\Source\Main\eSign\eSignWebMvc\Source\Red.eSign.WebMvc\Startup.cs:line 60
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
at eSignWebMVC.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\denkhnin\Documents\Source\Main\eSign\eSignWebMvc\Source\Red.eSign.WebMvc\Program.cs:line 34

From the stack trace "Startup.cs:line 60", The issue happens when this code is executed in the Startup class.
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperConfig());
});

I'm out of clues as to what's causing this

The internal property of an collection 'Item' is automaticly added to your mapping. You can fix it by adding .ForMember("Item", opt => opt.Ignore()); to your mapping.

I just had the same error as you, and it was a pretty obvious fix once I realised what was happening.  Assuming you're trying to return a collection of clients, not just a single.
mapper.Map<ClientView>(clients)

Change that to
mapper.Map<ClientView[]>(clients)

Your mapper config will just have the singular CreateMap<Client, ClientView>() and it'll work when you add the array modifier where you use it.
p.s.  You didn't show us where you were actually using your mapper, so I think that was a roadblock for you here in trying to get decent answers.

It's not a solution to your actual problem in .Net 8 but I had similar issues when I upgraded to .Net 8 from .net Core.
However .Net 6.0 seems to work with AutoMapper 8.0.0 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.0.0
Maybe use that as an interim measure and .Net 6 is supported for a few months yet.

In my case the problem was someone implemented Map<list<T1>, list<T2>>.
Same case after update for .NET8 and AutoMapper 13 I encountered similar message (not too much descriptive for me).
My solution was removing the list and "assume" AutoMapper is enough smart to map the list. Map<T1, T2>
I said "assume" because I added this in the startup:
public static List<TDestination> MapList<TSource, TDestination>(this IMapper mapper, List<TSource> source)
{
   return source.Select(x => mapper.Map<TDestination>(x)).ToList();
}


That's built in, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html.

Ohh, that's nice. Thanks Lucian.

I've found the problem with this, it's a bug with the latest version of AutoMapper running on .Net 8. The bug is this:
AutoMapper will not honor C# class indexers, as this:
public class MyClass

{
...
public IDictionary Properties
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        if (Properties != null)
        {
            if (Properties.Contains(propertyName))
                return (string) Properties[propertyName];
        
        return string.Empty;
    
    set
    {
        Properties[propertyName] = value;
    }
}


public string GetProperty(string propertyName)
{
    if (Properties != null)
    {
        if (Properties.Contains(propertyName))
            return (string)Properties[propertyName];
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

public void SetProperty(string propertyName, string value)
{
    if (Properties != null)
    {
        Properties[propertyName] = value;
    }
}

}
Notice the problem was with the
public string this[string propertyName]

The error message is very generic, but then after thinking of it, it came to me that the above could be it.
To resolve this, I introduced GetProperty and SetProperty functions instead.
Since this is a normal C# syntax and AutoMapper was working fine with it before, I hope they fix it. I'll open up a ticket about it.
Ninos
